# PHP index.php File get other pages content from subdirectory location

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, server-side

How to get only an `index.php` in the server root directory and have all linked pages like `/about.php` `/contact.php` and so on located in a subdirectory like `/pages/dist` in the server? If someone visits `example.com/about.php` it get's the content from `/pages/dist/[filename.php]` ?

Comment: Are you effectively wanting the .php to be stripped from the URL?

Comment: no that's ok because I use a .htacces with `Options +MultiViews` to have it work without the extension too. Just looking to have the other files in a subdirectory. I don't know why it got downvoted is the question so bad?

Comment: Is this a questions if its possible? Or you're having an issue trying to implement this?

Comment: it's more a question because I don't know if it's actually possible with using just one `index.php` for it. I can do this with includes but then I would need to add all pages to the root say: `about.php` and do an include to the file located at `/pages/dist/about.php/` to the server and that's bad for my project because I want to manage all pages that get displayed from the `/pages/dist/[filename.php]` I'm using task runners in a very complex project with many pages not sure if someone here knows if it's possible to do that's why I ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that I have found to do it.

1. **Using htaccess with regex:**

Using [rewrite engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you link the base url to a folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)([\w-_]+)$ pages/dist/$1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)([\w-_]+\.php)$ pages/dist/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The second line is for files that end without the .php tag, and the third with.
What this does is if the user inputs in the url *www.example.com/test.php* it will show what is on the *www.example.com/page/dist/test.php*, even if the user strips the php tag, but if he inputs the index.php it will stay the same.

---

2. **Using htaccess without regex:**

This one is just for the simplicity, but if we where not to use regex it could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule "test.php" "page/dist/test.php"
RewriteRule "test2.php" "page/dist/test2.php"
RewriteRule "test3.php" "page/dist/test3.php"
...
```

---

Please correct me if I'm wrong.